# Running SignalR server on VM and consuming by Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, signalr

**My goal:** I want to run SignalR server app (ASP.NET website hosting SignalR) and consume it by Xamarin app. Basically the server (website) must be accessible outside my local machine.. and here's my first problem.

**My env configuration:** I have a MacOSX and VMWare installed on it with fresh Windows 10 and VS2017. I just built a simplest possible SignalR web chat application. When I'm running it from VS, Google Chrome opens the browser with address: **localhost:49919** and It works:

[image]

**The problem:** Before I even start to consume it by mobile emulators I must be sure that this website is accessible a least in local network. So I typed in browser (in Windows VM): **10.0.1.58:49919** and it didn't work. 10.0.1.58 - this is my vm IP (network configuration is bridged). Same result when I opened this address on my Mac:

[image]

**My effort:**

1. I set vmware Network setting to "Bridged Networking" -> "Wi-fi" and got IP=10.0.1.58 (there is also an option of Autodetect)
2. I typed ipconfig and ifconfig on both machines:

Windows10 (vm):

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.58
```

On Mac (I'm not sure where to look), but I have:

```
lo0: 
    ...
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    ...
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: 
    ...
    inet 10.0.1.54 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.1.255
    ...
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: 
    ...
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: 
    ...
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 4a:00:07:58:56:b0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: 
    ...
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: 
    ...
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: 
    ...
    inet6 fe80::c3a4:bc19:f3f9:a5e7%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    ...
vmnet1: 
    ...
    inet 192.168.89.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.89.255
vmnet8: 
    ...
    inet 192.168.42.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.42.255
```

3. I turned off firewall and keep it disabled for entire time
4. I complie and run the project: I see "http://localhost:49919/Default.aspx" in the browser - it works!
5. I open new tab with this address: "http://10.0.1.58:49919/Default.aspx", and I have (same on windows and on mac) this error:

[image]

6. I tried the same with a totally wrong IP (there is no ping for 10.0.1.99) just to see if the results are the same, so: "http://10.0.1.99:49919/Default.aspx". This result:
   [image]

So.. it doesn't work, and I meet all **Dennis1679** conditions (in his first answer).. I think.. But...I've done two more things:

7. In this file: `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` of my VS solution, I changed the "localhost" to real ip "10.0.1.58".

So change this line:

```
<binding>binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49919:localhost</binding>
```

into this line:

```
<binding>binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49919:10.0.1.58"</binding>
```

then... I resterted IIS (in cmd line iisreset command), restered VS, run the project and... didn't work. Same result - "Invalid Hostname". So still `localhost:49919/Default.aspx` works, but `10.0.1.58:49919/Default.aspx` does NOT :/

8. Last step(s).. I removed `.vs` folder so I know sln config is clean, restarted VS and:

   - Run Power Shell as admin
   - run this command: netsh http add urlacl url=http://10.0.1.58:49919/ user=everyone
   - "URL reservation successfully added"
   - restert IIS (in cmd line `iisreset` command)
   - change the "localhost" to real ip "10.0.1.58" in this file `.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

   AND... the result is a little bit different, so that's interesting: 
   [image]

So something happened... But I can't go anywhere from there...

Comment: Hey Louisa, do you mean by `accessible from outside` that you want someone from outside of your home network be able to access that server, or do you instead mean you want someone on your network to be able to access the server? Because in the first case it would mean opening up ports in your routers configuration. In the second case, make sure that your Network settings on VMware is in Bridged mode so that your virtual machine is on the same subnet as the host. Tip: Try a simple ping command from Mac -> Windows or Windows -> Mac and see if you get a response with packets.

Comment: @Dennis1679 thanks for the comment! well I want this service to be accessible from Mac (technically it's seen as a separate cpu on the network). But my problem is way earlier. I have this website, when I type "localhost:port" in the browser - I got my chat, but when I type "realIP:port" It doesn't work. Of course I can ping my IP from windows vm (localhost) and from mac as well. They are clearly on the same network can ping each other.

Comment: Okay, two more things. First of all, are you trying to surf to 10.0.1.58:49919 on your Windows machine? Because that's not the same as browsing to `localhost:49919`. Localhost is `127.0.0.1` and you would only type 10.0.1.58 from any other device that is not running the website (eg. the mac or a phone). Second is that you should have added the <binding></binding> and not changed the line you had there already.

Comment: Then you run `netsh http add urlacl url=http://10.0.1.58:123456/ user=everyone` and after that `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=58938 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow` to create the rule if you haven't already done that.

Comment: @Dennis1679 oh my.. The problem was actually in the "binding" line! Thanks very much!!

Comment: glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You just installed new windows10, vs2017 and created empty website with singnalR server.. What do you do access this website/chat from Mac?`

Two things I can conclude from your post.

1. **Your IIS Express server is running.**

Meaning that you can access your website from your Windows 10 machine.

2. **One (or both operating) system(s) operate on the 10.0.1.xx subnet.** *It says so in the error message.*

You say you are running VMware.
Now a couple things can be causing the problem to communicate between devices.

- Your Network Device settings in VMware of the **guest** machine(*windows 10*) is **not** set to `bridged` mode. Meaning your Windows might be on the IP range of `10.0.1.xx` and your **host** machine(*MAC*) on the `192.168.1.xx` network.

**Conclusion** *Only if you select bridged network mode for the VMware network settings of the guest machine, only then will you be on the same subnet automatically.*

**The question is**:

`What do you do access this website/chat from Mac?`

1 . Make sure the VMware network card of the Guest machine(*WIN10*) is in **bridged mode**.

- [*On Windows*] pressing `WINkey+R` type `cmd` and type `ipconfig`. Check what your, depending on how you connect to your internet, IPv4 Address is for your Wireless or Ethernet card.
- [*On MAC*] open up the terminal, eg. by pressing `cmd+space` and typing `terminal`.
  Then type `ifconfig` and hit enter.

If those are the same, next step.

2. Add binding lines to `.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

In the applicationhost.config file you have a line that says 
`<binding>binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49919:localhost</binding>`

**Add a new line** below this one current `<binding></binding>` with your guest machine's IP address.

Eg. `<binding>binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49919:192.168.0.12</binding>`

Now save the file and continue to the next step.

3. You **open a port** in the Windows firewall *(or turn it off, but I recommend against it.)*

   - Open the port on your guest machine (*Control Panel > System and Security > Firewall > Advanced settings and add Inbound rule*)

Done that? Step 4.

4. On your Mac go to your browser. Go to `10.0.1.xxx:port`.

Right now, if you followed all the steps correctly, you should be able to see the website.

If at this point it still isn't working and you need more help, please edit your question to explain what is happening. Or head on over to [networkengineering.stackexchange.com](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com), they are there for network problems.

Comment: Thx Dennis, I just went back to the snapshot after installation (and update) of windows 10, so I know VM is fresh. I will go through your points but I have quick follow up question about `If those are the same, next step.` part. On mac I'm looking at `ifconfig` results and and there is quite a lot of stuff. Should I look at `en0` (here I have inet 10.0.1.54) or at the end I have `vmnet1` with inet=192.168.x.1 and `vmnet8` with inet=192.168.y.1 (different then vmnet1). Oh and I set my vm to "Bridged Networking" -> "Wi-fi" and got IP=10.0.1.54 (running ipconfig in windows10)

Comment: Sorry, on windows10 vm I have IP=10.0.1.58

Comment: Hi, Please have a look at my updated question. It was a little bit chaotic, I've cleaned it so I hope it's all clear what I'm doing.

Comment: The problem was with the "binding" line. Look at comments to the question ^^